# Apache CXF failed by generating of Client webservice after adding cxf-rt-transports-http dependency

Tags: maven, wsdl, cxf

I am trying to generate a JAVA based Webservice client from an existing WSDL with it's related XSD files using Apache CXF. To do this i use a maven configuration file listed below which basicall works well.

```html
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.testcamera</groupId>
 <artifactId>TestCamera</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>TestCamera Maven App</name>
 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <tomcat.version>9.0.4</tomcat.version>
  <cxf.version>3.2.2</cxf.version>
 </properties>
 <build>
  <!-- <finalName>???</finalName> -->
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>${java.version}</source>
     <target>${java.version}</target>
     <!-- encoding>UTF-8</encoding -->
     <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
     <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${cxf.version}</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>generate-sources</id>
   <phase>generate-sources</phase>
   <configuration>
    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
    <wsdlOptions>
     <wsdlOption>
      <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdls/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl</wsdl>
     </wsdlOption>
    </wsdlOptions>
   </configuration>
   <goals>
    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
   </goals>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
  </plugins>
  <resources>
   <resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
   </resource>
   <resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
     <include>**</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
     <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
   </resource>
  </resources>
  <testResources>
   <testResource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
   </testResource>
   <testResource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/test/java</directory>
    <includes>
     <include>**</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
     <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
   </testResource>
  </testResources>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
   <version>${cxf.version}</version>
  </dependency>
<!--   <dependency> -->
<!--    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> -->
<!--    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId> -->
<!--    <version>${cxf.version}</version> -->
<!--   </dependency> -->
  <!-- Jetty is needed if you're are not using the CXFServlet -->
<!--   <dependency> -->
<!--    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> -->
<!--    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId> -->
<!--    <version>${cxf.version}</version> -->
<!--   </dependency> -->
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

The problem is that i need to add proxy support to this web service. That is why i need to add following dependencies to my maven dependencies which cause problem and show me an error. 
Here the related POM.xml:

```
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
       <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
       <version>${cxf.version}</version>
      </dependency>
```

And related Error Message after aftivation of cxf-rt-transports-http

```js
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument (WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema (WSDLReaderImpl.java:830)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema (WSDLReaderImpl.java:864)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema (WSDLReaderImpl.java:654)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes (WSDLReaderImpl.java:610)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions (WSDLReaderImpl.java:320)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL (WSDLReaderImpl.java:2352)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL (WSDLReaderImpl.java:2338)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition (WSDLManagerImpl.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition (WSDLManagerImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.parseWSDL (WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.build (WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:71)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build (JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build (JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl (WSDLToJavaContainer.java:195)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute (WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute (WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool (ToolRunner.java:105)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run (WSDLToJava.java:113)
```

It will be great if someone know why that behavior happens!

The related WSDL is available under following url: 
https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl
Note: To see content of wsdl you need right click on that page and see source code!

Thanks in advance! 
kami

Comment: Location which you've pointed does not look like actual wsdl file but it looks like description of wsdl.

Comment: To see the WSDL file, right click on the page --> view source code. Then you see the WSDL.